# Show own Windows 8 App in Start page

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, tile

i am currently developing a Windows 8.1 app, trying to use live tiles.

The problem is, that the tile isn't showing up within the Windows Start Page. How do i let the tile appear? Are there any options in Visual Studio 2013?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows 8.1, tiles aren't automatically pinned to Start for newly installed store apps like they were in Windows 8 - this is as true when Visual Studio is installing the in-development build as it is when users install it from the store.

You need to pin the tile to the start screen yourself. You can do that by either searching for the app's name or going to the "All Apps" view of the start menu and finding it there.